# Server-side pagination using ngx-pagination

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I got the ngx-pagination module working with all the listings in the GET, but I want the pagination to work server-side too, but I'm unsure how to implement it further than what I have. I'm looking at the documentation for ngx-pagination, but I'm a little bit confused. Here's what I have.

**html code**

```
<body [ngClass]="[(this.isOpen && this.mobile) || (this.isOpen && this.tablet) ? 'hideContent' : 'showContent']">
    <div class="loading">
        <!-- <mat-spinner class="loader" *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner> -->

        <ngx-spinner id="loadingIcon" *ngIf="isLoading" type="cog" size="large" color="#3071a9">


            <p class="loadingTitle">Loading...</p>
        </ngx-spinner>

    </div>

    <div class="spacing"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters"
            *ngIf="!this.isOpen && this.mobile || this.isOpen && !this.mobile || !this.isOpen && !this.mobile">
            <div class="class col-md-7"></div>

        </div>

        <!-- /|slice:0:show -->
        <!--; let i = index-->
        <div class="row"
            *ngFor="let auction of posts | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: this.posts.count }">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-centered">

                <div class="listingCard" [@simpleFadeAnimation]="'in'">

                    <div class=container>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div id="title">{{auction.title}}</div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>

</body>

</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body [ngClass]="[(this.isOpen && this.mobile) || (this.isOpen && this.tablet) ? 'hideContent' : 'showContent']">
    <div class="loading">
        <!-- <mat-spinner class="loader" *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner> -->
        <ngx-spinner id="loadingIcon" *ngIf="isLoading" type="cog" size="large" color="#3071a9">

            <p class="loadingTitle">Loading...</p>
        </ngx-spinner>
    </div>
    <div class="spacing"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters"
            *ngIf="!this.isOpen && this.mobile || this.isOpen && !this.mobile || !this.isOpen && !this.mobile">
            <div class="class col-md-7"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /|slice:0:show -->
        <!--; let i = index-->
        <div class="row"
            *ngFor="let auction of posts | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: this.posts.count }">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-centered">
                <div class="listingCard" [@simpleFadeAnimation]="'in'">
                    <div class=container>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div id="title">{{listing.title}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    =
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
</body>
```

**.ts File** component

```
 p: number = 1;

ngOnInit(){
    this.submitListingService.getListings(this.postsPerPage, this.currentPage);
    this.listingService
      .getPostUpdateListener()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
      .subscribe((postData: { listing: Listing[]; postCount: number }) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.totalPosts = postData.postCount;
        this.posts = postData.listing;
        this.filteredPosts = postData.listing;
      });
}
```

**Angular service**

```
getListings(postsPerPage: number, currentPage: number) {
    let listings = "Get Listings";
    const params = new HttpParams().set("listings", listings);
    const queryParams = `?pagesize=${postsPerPage}&page=${currentPage}`;
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; posts: any; maxPosts: number }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/listings" + queryParams,
        { params }
      )
      .pipe(
        map(postData => {
          return {
            posts: postData.posts.map(post => {
              return {
               title: post.title,                   
                id: post._id
              };
            }),
            maxPosts: postData.maxPosts
          };
        })
      )
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
      .subscribe(transformedPostData => {
        this.posts = transformedPostData.posts;
        this.postsUpdated.next({
          listing: [...this.posts],
          postCount: transformedPostData.maxPosts
        });
      });
  }
```

*-> Server Code* 
**app.js**

```
app.get("/api/listings", (req, res, next) => {
  Post.find({ auctionEndDateTime: { $gte: Date.now() } })
      .populate("creator", "username")
      .then(documents => {
        req.params.Id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.Id);
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Auction listings retrieved successfully!",
          posts: documents
        });
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do this. 
This might be a better fit for your case.

```
  Post.find({ auctionEndDateTime: { $gte: Date.now() } })
      .populate("creator", "username")
      .then(documents => {
          req.params.Id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.Id);

          let per_page = req.query.pagesize;
          let page = req.query.page || 1;
          let offset = (page - 1) * per_page;
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Auction listings retrieved successfully!",
          posts: documents.slice(offset).slice(0,
                per_page)

        });
      });
```

and here is one more approach using `slice`

```
  var skip = req.query.pagesize * (req.query.page - 1)

        Post.where('auctionEndDateTime').gte(Date.now()).slice([skip, req.query.pagesize])
                      .populate("creator", "username")
                      .then(documents => {

              res.status(200).json({
                 message: "Auction listings retrieved successfully!",
                 posts: documents
              });
          })
```

Comment: I currently have 32 listings. When I add your code, it grabs all of them instead of the first 10. If I add .limit(10) then I only get page number ```1``` in the pagination. There is no option for page 2 and beyond if using .limit(). I need it to only grab 10 at a time while at the same time showing all the pages I'm currently not on. Here's my updated code https://pastebin.com/vJbzF3wB

Comment: Do you get `req.query.pagesize` and `req.query.page` on the server side ? The solution should work without `.limit` but the other solutions with `skip` and `limit` should work also this is just a different approach but I feel your problem is on the client side.

Comment: I modified your code and added limit and got it working, but I think there's something wrong with the logic. I now only get 10 items per page and it grabs the next page from the server like I want. In my 32 listing example, when I get to page 4, it has 10 items and when I click back to page 3, it has the last 2? Is there something in my code on the backend that would cause this? Updated code: https://pastebin.com/qdmL25CP.

Comment: Not really sure why, but your edited solution breaks my code on the frontend. I load your changes and console says ```v.parent.context.$implicit.watchingGroup is undefined"``` (it's a value that the listings supposed return) https://pastebin.com/ap7uuzx1

Comment: you don't need the code from the first solution just send the docs

Comment: I updated it to reflect your latest change, but ```{ $slice: [skip, req.query.pagesize] }``` breaks the code. I added a console.log(documents) after .then and it returns the results, but only the _id field. The other field don't appear. This would explain the code breaking on frontend, but why isn't it returning all the fields like before? Also it's returning 32 _ids not 10

Comment: With your edit, it says ```Error: slice() must be used after where() when called with these arguments```

Comment: I am now returning results to the frontend, but it returns all 32 results. Not 10 of them? Also like in that example here: https://pastebin.com/qdmL25CP  Don't I need to get the totalPosts first, then in a separate query, get the first 10. This way I can assign totalPosts to the mat-paginator and it spread the totalPosts across pages while only having 10 results at a time? Otherwise paginator would have no idea how many pages to reflect backend.   Currently it doesn't return the total posts, which I think is needed to make this work, but I could be wrong

Comment: use the values from the params if you chose to send them this way but don't use both the `skip` and `limit` and the slice when you get the docs

Comment: I tried removing slice and keeping skip and limit, but either way it does that weird thing I mentioned before where in my 32 listing example, when I get to page 4, it has 10 items and when I click back to page 3, it has the last 2 in this example: https://pastebin.com/qdmL25CP? Do you know why that is? If I set this.currentPage = 4 on the frontend on ngOnit() then the first page appears with 2 listings like it should. But not when I initialize at 1 and move to page 4

Comment: then maybe `this.currentPage` doesn't get updated correctly

Comment: I got it working! I used this code: https://pastebin.com/bN9NpFpg  Also the issue with the pagination was because I used a variable instead of (pageChange)="$event") Now it's pushing correct number that corresponds to paginator page. Originally it was (pageChange)="this.currentPage" which was throwing it off. One more question though. Is the way I made my backend chaining the queries together considered ok or is that considered bad practice and could cause problems?

Comment: You can use `countDocuments()` instead of the first query and you will be perfect

Comment: Ok. I changed Post.find() to post.countDocuments(). Seems to still be working. I'll release the bounty to you for all your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need two values on server side one is page i.e. which page number to show and second is limit i.e. how many results to show on the page. 
Then just use:

```
.skip(limit * (page - 1)).limit(limit)
```

First operator will skip the unwanted results for eg: if page is 2 and limit is 20 then in first operation the first 20 results will be skipped then in second operation we will limit the result to 20 results so you will get documents 21 to 40 which is desired result.

Comment: While that does limit the page to whatever limit I set. Let say 10 for example, it only shows 10 and the ngx-paginator becomes greyed out. How do I limit it, but still be able to get the next 10 for the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Service File** ,

```
getListings(postsPerPage: number, currentPage: number) {
    // let listings = "Get Listings";
    // const params = new HttpParams().set("listings", listings);
    // const queryParams = `?pagesize=${postsPerPage}&page=${currentPage}`;
    const queryParams = postsPerPage+"/"+currentPage; //change this .
    this.http
    .get<{ message: string; posts: any; maxPosts: number }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/listings/" + queryParams
        )
    .pipe(
        map(postData => {
            return {
                posts: postData.posts.map(post => {
                    return {
                        title: post.title,                   
                        id: post._id
                    };
                }),
                maxPosts: postData.maxPosts
            };
        })
        )
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
    .subscribe(transformedPostData => {
        this.posts = transformedPostData.posts;
        this.postsUpdated.next({
            listing: [...this.posts],
            postCount: transformedPostData.maxPosts
        });
    });
}
```

As you are sending parameters so you need to change the URL of API as below i mentioned in server code ,

Your **Server code** will be as follow ,

```
app.get("/api/listings/:postPerPage/:currentPage", (req, res, next) => {
    let postPerPage = req.params.postPerPage;
    let currentPage = req.params.currentPage;
    Post.find({ auctionEndDateTime: { $gte: Date.now() } })
    .populate("creator username")
    .skip(postPerPage * currentPage)
    .limit(postPerPage)
    .then(documents => {
        req.params.Id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.Id);
        res.status(200).json({
            message: "Auction listings retrieved successfully!",
            posts: documents
        });
    });
});
```

From the above code you will get the post equals to *postPerPage* . 

Hope this is what you looking for . Thank you

Comment: I added your code and I currently have 12 listings. So the last 2 should be available on page 2, but the ngx-paginator has greyed out any options, but page 1. I can't go to page 2. If I comment out .limit(), then I can see page 2, but I can't go to it. I outputted the value of clicking the next button on paginator and it says 2 like it should, but I'm not on page 2 and I can't go back to 1 unless I refresh page. (Listings never change at all when clicking paginator) Here's a reference to html https://pastebin.com/9pzVidJ6